# Why does the first call to a TensorFlow function execute much slower than the second call?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, image-classification, performance

I was doing an Image Classification problem using TensorFlow. I was generating the mean images for two image datasets having the same size. The dataset was generated using the **tf.data API**. Thereafter I took a **sample of 100 images from each dataset** and **generated the mean image for both**:

```
sample_dataset1 = dataset1.take(100)
sample_dataset2 = dataset2.take(100)

start_time1 = time.time()
mean_img1 = get_mean_image(sample_dataset1)
end_time1 = time.time()

start_time2 = time.time()
mean_img2 = get_mean_image(sample_dataset2)
end_time2 = time.time()
```

I repeated the experiment 5 times. While calling the **get_mean_image()** function multiple times, I noticed some strange behaviour. **Despite both the sample datasets having the same shape i.e. (100, 256, 256), the time taken by both of these was different**:

```
   Time taken by SAMPLE_DATASET1  Time taken by SAMPLE_DATASET2
0                     104.871432                      28.818614
1                     156.577945                      37.301727
2                     128.607475                      15.428025
3                      69.504744                      20.412712
4                      93.292305                      33.781078
```

My questions:

**Q.1: Why does the first call take much mote time than the second call? Is it due to parallel computing?**

**Q.2: In case the delay is caused by some overhead, what steps can be taken to reduce the time taken by the first call?**

Thanks in advance.

**P.S.:**

The method used to create the datasets from which the samples of 100 images were taken:

```
def create_dataset(file_pattern: str) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    # getting file blobs:
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern)

    # reading the image files:
    dataset = dataset.map(
        map_func = tf.io.read_file,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )

    # decoding the JPEG files:
    dataset = dataset.map(
        map_func = tf.image.decode_jpeg,
        num_parallel_calls = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )

    # resizing the files to (256,256) and picking the first channel of Grayscale image:
    dataset = dataset.map(
        map_func = lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, (256,256))[:,:,0]/255,
        num_parallel_calls = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )

    # casting matrix values as float (64-bits) to avoid data-type mismatch:
    dataset = dataset.map(
        map_func = lambda x: tf.cast(x, tf.float64),
        num_parallel_calls = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )

    return dataset
```

The function to get the mean image for a given dataset (including the sample):

```
def get_mean_image(dataset: tf.data.Dataset) -> tf.Tensor:

    # getting the number of images and
    #casting it to float (64-bit) to avoid data-type mismatch:
    dataset_size = tf.cast(
        x = dataset.cardinality(),
        dtype = tf.float64
    )

    # getting the sum of the images:
    sum_img = dataset.reduce(
        initial_state = tf.zeros(
            shape = (256, 256),
            dtype = tf.float64
        ),
        reduce_func = lambda x,y: x+y
    )

    # getting the mean image:
    mean_img = sum_img/dataset_size

    return mean_img
```